# if statement conditions specified in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
array = ["ProgA", "ProgC", "ProgG"]
```

This array can change depending on the user input.

I have the following Json File:

```
    {"ABC":{

        "ProgA": 1, 
        "ProgB": 0, 
        "ProgC": 1,  
        "ProgD": 0, 
        "ProgE": 0, 
        "ProgF": 1, 
        "ProgG": 1, 
        "ProgH": 0 


    },
    "DEF":{

        "ProgA": 1, 
        "ProgB": 0, 
        "ProgC": 0,  
        "ProgD": 0, 
        "ProgE": 1, 
        "ProgF": 0, 
        "ProgG": 1, 
        "ProgH": 0 


    },
    "GHI":{

        "ProgA": 1, 
        "ProgB": 1, 
        "ProgC": 1,  
        "ProgD": 1, 
        "ProgE": 1, 
        "ProgF": 1, 
        "ProgG": 1, 
        "ProgH": 1


    },
    "JKL":{

        "ProgA": 1, 
        "ProgB": 0, 
        "ProgC": 1,  
        "ProgD": 1, 
        "ProgE": 0, 
        "ProgF": 1, 
        "ProgG": 0, 
        "ProgH": 1 


    },
    "MNO":{

        "ProgA": 1, 
        "ProgB": 1, 
        "ProgC": 1,  
        "ProgD": 0, 
        "ProgE": 1, 
        "ProgF": 1, 
        "ProgG": 1, 
        "ProgH": 1

    }}
```

My goal is to basically return all the names ("ABC", "DEF" etc) which have the ProgA, ProgC and ProgG == 1

I am not sure how to evaluate the `if` statements when the conditions are in an array which can change.

Comment: `console.log(obj.ABC[ array[1] ])` will show the value of the `"ProgC"` switch inside `ABC` (`obj` is the variable name of he json object)

Comment: Loop over the object. Look over the array, look at value in object, see if all values equal to one, if true, you add it to an array

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, but, you access the array same way as you would when they could not change. That is why it is an array to allow it.

Comment: @Dellirium I should have been more clear. Even if array doesn't change, i am not sure how to proceed.  suppose i only had to return say all the things with `ProgA == 1", i can write a simple if loop to check but if there are multiple things to check, I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: @you would have to check within the loop, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/0mwpxpc6/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with `filter()` and `every()`

```js
var array = ["ProgA", "ProgC", "ProgG"];
var obj = {"ABC":{"ProgA":1,"ProgB":0,"ProgC":1,"ProgD":0,"ProgE":0,"ProgF":1,"ProgG":1,"ProgH":0},"DEF":{"ProgA":1,"ProgB":0,"ProgC":0,"ProgD":0,"ProgE":1,"ProgF":0,"ProgG":1,"ProgH":0},"GHI":{"ProgA":1,"ProgB":1,"ProgC":1,"ProgD":1,"ProgE":1,"ProgF":1,"ProgG":1,"ProgH":1},"JKL":{"ProgA":1,"ProgB":0,"ProgC":1,"ProgD":1,"ProgE":0,"ProgF":1,"ProgG":0,"ProgH":1},"MNO":{"ProgA":1,"ProgB":1,"ProgC":1,"ProgD":0,"ProgE":1,"ProgF":1,"ProgG":1,"ProgH":1}}

var result = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(e) {
  return array.every(function(a) {
    return obj[e][a] == 1;
  });
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: +1 to this answer for using `.keys`, `.filter` and `.every`, that's the cleanest approach in my opinion.

Comment: @briosheje Thanks :)

Comment: @NenadVracar Worked like charm. You are a genius.

Comment: @NenadVracar   any idea how would the code change if it were OR. I mean return the name if any of the progA, ProgC, ProgG is == 1?

Comment: @Morpheus Yes, instead of `every` you can use `some`

Answer (score 3):

Old-school approach: Loop over your JSON object, loop over your array input, use a flag to check whether they all match or not:

```js
var arr = ["ProgA", "ProgC", "ProgG"]
var o = {"ABC":{"ProgA":1,"ProgB":0,"ProgC":1,"ProgD":0,"ProgE":0,"ProgF":1,"ProgG":1,"ProgH":0},"DEF":{"ProgA":1,"ProgB":0,"ProgC":0,"ProgD":0,"ProgE":1,"ProgF":0,"ProgG":1,"ProgH":0},"GHI":{"ProgA":1,"ProgB":1,"ProgC":1,"ProgD":1,"ProgE":1,"ProgF":1,"ProgG":1,"ProgH":1},"JKL":{"ProgA":1,"ProgB":0,"ProgC":1,"ProgD":1,"ProgE":0,"ProgF":1,"ProgG":0,"ProgH":1},"MNO":{"ProgA":1,"ProgB":1,"ProgC":1,"ProgD":0,"ProgE":1,"ProgF":1,"ProgG":1,"ProgH":1}}

var out = [];
for(var i in o){                        // loop over the object
  var good = true;                      // set the flag
  for(var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++){  // loop over the input array
    if (o[i][arr[a]] != 1) {            // check if it doesn't match
      good = false;                     // if so, unset the flag
      break;                            // and break the inner loop
    }
  }
  if (good) out.push(i);     // if the flag is set, we have a match
}

console.log(out);
```

Comment: @naveen, haha, identical! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
var mainobj =  {"ABC":{

    "ProgA": 1, 
    "ProgB": 0, 
    "ProgC": 1,  
    "ProgD": 0, 
    "ProgE": 0, 
    "ProgF": 1, 
    "ProgG": 1, 
    "ProgH": 0 


},
"DEF":{

    "ProgA": 1, 
    "ProgB": 0, 
    "ProgC": 0,  
    "ProgD": 0, 
    "ProgE": 1, 
    "ProgF": 0, 
    "ProgG": 1, 
    "ProgH": 0 


},
"GHI":{

    "ProgA": 1, 
    "ProgB": 1, 
    "ProgC": 1,  
    "ProgD": 1, 
    "ProgE": 1, 
    "ProgF": 1, 
    "ProgG": 1, 
    "ProgH": 1


},
"JKL":{

    "ProgA": 1, 
    "ProgB": 0, 
    "ProgC": 1,  
    "ProgD": 1, 
    "ProgE": 0, 
    "ProgF": 1, 
    "ProgG": 0, 
    "ProgH": 1 


},
"MNO":{

    "ProgA": 1, 
    "ProgB": 1, 
    "ProgC": 1,  
    "ProgD": 0, 
    "ProgE": 1, 
    "ProgF": 1, 
    "ProgG": 1, 
    "ProgH": 1

}}

var result = [];

for(var obj in mainobj){
  console.log(mainobj[obj]['ProgA'])
  if(mainobj[obj]['ProgA'] && mainobj[obj]['ProgC'] && mainobj[obj]['ProgG']){
   result.push(obj);
}
 }

console.log(result);
console.log(result);
```